# Is there a way to get a more real-time view of a user's News Feed?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I can search an individual user's News Feed, restricted to that user's friends using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=youtube.com
```

The [documentation](http://developers.connect.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) says it will retrieve an outdated view of the News Feed.  Is there a way to get a more real-time view of a user's News Feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the talent at Facebook, its not likely that the out-dated aspect of this api call is a bug. If I had to guess, they do it so that their apps/site remain the center of usage (very smart business decision, really, especially when you look at the situation that Twitter has found itself in). So short answer: no.

Comment: That's what I thought too but then I started using the Squirl iPad app.  They display recent videos that each of my friends have posted, sorted by friend.  Do you have an idea as to how they get this data?  Is there something else to use besides the Graph API?

Comment: Ya, FQL is likely the most straightforward method for that. Get all the videos of the users current friends, sorted by time.

They'll run something like SELECT * FROM video WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid1,uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() or uid2=me()) ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 50

Comment: So if the data is available via FQL, I'm curious how it relates to what you meant in the original post.  Perhaps I don't understand the difference between the Graph API and FQL.

Comment: Graph API and FQL are meant for different purposes. You can't really perform in-depth "queries" on the graph, other than a search. So FQL does that. So you could collect all the data that is in the newsfeed, yes, but you won't know whats in the newsfeed and whats not. Because very, very few of your friends actions actually appear in your newsfeed.

In summary: you can query all that data that facebook could use for their newsfeed. But you'll never know what their newsfeed actually looks like.

Here's some docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to get a more real-time view of the user's newsfeed. I believe Facebook reserves this functionality so developers don't build their own FB clients.

Comment: That's what I thought too but then I started using the Squirl iPad app. They display recent videos that each of my friends have posted, sorted by friend. Do you have an idea as to how they get this data? Is there something else to use besides the Graph API?

Comment: I don't know how you'd get those uploads without using the OG API. With it, you can grab them for an individual friend like this: https://graph.facebook.com/{friend_id}/videos/uploaded?access_token=...